# Search query with checkbox modifiers in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic search in Django based on the selected checkboxes like in the below picture:
[image: Sample Seachbox]

I have read the official documentation around the queries but I got stuck creating the query considering the modifiers.

The search works if I hardcode the filters, however the idea is the users to be able to multiple criteria searches.

I get the selected checkboxes from the form in a list, and the search value as "q" variable.
Then I fail to figure out how to make the filter criteria dynamic as to get the needed queryset and return it to the search results page

```
def index(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        filters = request.GET.getlist('filters')

# Here I want to iterate trough the filters list list and set it dynamically 
# in the below query as filter based on the selected checkboxes listed 
# in the filters list received from the form.

        multiple_q = (Q(subject_name__icontains=q) | Q(business_service__icontains=q) |
                      Q(assignment_group__icontains=q) | Q(comment__icontains=q))

        data = Data.objects.filter(multiple_q)

    context = {
        'data': data
    }
    
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

I have tried constructing the Q query as a string but it is then not performing the query as supposed to.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is interested in the solution I found for my case this is how it worked:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def index(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = str(request.GET['q'])
        filters = request.GET.getlist('filters')
        queryset = []
        for filter in filters:
            filter_concat = '%s__icontains' % filter
            queryset.append(Q(**{filter_concat: q}))
        result = reduce(or_, queryset)
        data = Data.objects.filter(result).order_by('id')

    context = {
        'data': data
    }
    
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```